# centering the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, templates

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%------------------------------ colors
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} % use colors on table and more
\definecolor{333}{RGB}{51, 51, 51} % define custom color
%------------------------------ source code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray},
  captionpos=b,
  frame=shadowbox,
  language=HTML,
  rulesepcolor=\color{333},
  tabsize=2
}
%------------------------------ define Abstract environment, missing in the 'book' class
\newenvironment{abstract}{\cleardoublepage \null \vfill \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname \end{center}}{\vfill\null}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\abstractname{Sommario}} % change Abstract title
%------------------------------ active url
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\color{black}\small\ttfamily}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % active ref
\usepackage{showframe}
%------------------------------ macros
\newcommand{\sectionname}{Section} % define Section ref
\newcommand{\subsectionname}{Sub-section} % define Sub-section ref
\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.4} % tables padding


\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage} %------------------------------ TITLE PAGE
\begin{center}
\vbox to0pt{\vbox to\textheight{\vfill \includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{images/unipd-light} \vfill}\vss}

\hspace{0.0cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%{.20\textwidth}
  \centering
  \hspace{-0.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{images/logo_unipd}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
    \centering
  \begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \hspace{-0.02cm}\scshape{\Large{\bfseries{Università degli Studi di Padova}}} \\
  %\hline \\
  \vspace{0.2cm}
  \hspace{-0.22cm}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.5pt}}\\
  \hspace{0.027cm}\hspace{-0.43cm}\scshape{\Large{Dipartimento di Ingegenria Industriale DII}} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\hspace{-0.09cm}\large{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria dell'Energia Elettrica} \\
\vspace{2.25cm}
\scshape{\Large{\bfseries{Analysis of an innovative distribution system through a novel optimal power flow algorithm}}} 
\end{center}

\vfill
\begin{normalsize}
\begin{flushleft}
  \hspace{57pt} \textit{Laureando} \hspace{167pt} \textit{Relatore}\\
  \vspace{5pt}
  \hspace{30pt} \large{\textbf{Tommaso Faedo}} \hspace{70pt} \large{\textbf{Prof. Roberto Turri}}\\
  \vspace{10pt}
  \hspace{275pt} \normalsize{\textit{Correlatore}}\\
  \vspace{5pt}
  \hspace{241pt} \large{\textbf{Prof. Paolo Tenti}}\\
  \vspace{5pt}
  \hspace{172pt} \large{\textbf{Ing. Tommaso Caldognetto}}\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{normalsize}

\vfill
\begin{center}
\hspace{-0.15cm}
\line(1, 0){360}

\hspace{0.01cm}\textsc{Anno Accademico 2017/2018}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Hi, this is my cover of the thesis. I don't know why the elements, such as the title or the red logo of the University, are not centered (vertically) into the main rectangle (the main rectangle shows the boundary of the paper). I add the \hspace but I want to know if there is a system that automatically put in the center (vertically) the object. I tried with \centering but every time every elements aren't perfectly in the center (vertically) of the main rectangle. Thanks

Comment: Just a comment: you might want to change `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to correct the "Università".

Comment: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} give wrong representation

Comment: Weird... For me, with `latin1` I get "UniversitÃ", and with `utf8` I get "Università"... Anyway, just a comment `:)`

Comment: @TommasoFaedo: Which editor do you use? Do you want these elements be centred w.r.t. the physical page  or w.r.t. the printing area?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If the file is ISO encoded `latin1` should be used.

Comment: @TommasoFaedo, `\centering` is for horizontal alignment.

Comment: The `table` environment is completely useless as are the two `minipage`s. Are you aware of the `frontespizio` package?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik this site is utf-8 encoded, so the fact that the text is utf8 encoded here is no indication of the encoding of the OP's original file (which is why debugging encoding errors via the website is tricky:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to center your text vertically. For this, you should add a `\vspace*{\fill}` right after the `\begin{titlepage}`, and a `\vfill` right before the `\end{titlepage}`. (Sorry, if this was not your question.) I also changed encoding to `utf8`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%------------------------------ colors
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} % use colors on table and more
\definecolor{333}{RGB}{51, 51, 51} % define custom color
%------------------------------ source code
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\sffamily,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray},
    captionpos=b,
    frame=shadowbox,
    language=HTML,
    rulesepcolor=\color{333},
    tabsize=2
}
%------------------------------ define Abstract environment, missing in the 'book' class
\newenvironment{abstract}{\cleardoublepage \null \vfill \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname \end{center}}{\vfill\null}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\abstractname{Sommario}} % change Abstract title
%------------------------------ active url
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\color{black}\small\ttfamily}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % active ref
\usepackage{showframe}
%------------------------------ macros
\newcommand{\sectionname}{Section} % define Section ref
\newcommand{\subsectionname}{Sub-section} % define Sub-section ref
\renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.4} % tables padding


\begin{document}
    \frontmatter

    \begin{titlepage} %------------------------------ TITLE PAGE
\vspace*{\fill}

        \begin{center}
            \vbox to0pt{\vbox to\textheight{\vfill \includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{images/unipd-light} \vfill}\vss}

            \hspace{0.0cm}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%{.20\textwidth}
                \centering
                \hspace{-0.005cm}\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{images/logo_unipd}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
                \centering
                \begin{table}[H]
                    \begin{tabular}{c}
                        \hspace{-0.02cm}\scshape{\Large{\bfseries{Università degli Studi di Padova}}} \\
                        %\hline \\
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        \hspace{-0.22cm}\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0.9\textwidth}{0.5pt}}\\
                        \hspace{0.027cm}\hspace{-0.43cm}\scshape{\Large{Dipartimento di Ingegenria Industriale DII}} \\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{table}
            \end{minipage}

            \vspace{0.5cm}
            \hspace{-0.09cm}\large{Corso di Laurea Magistrale in Ingegneria dell'Energia Elettrica} \\
            \vspace{2.25cm}
            \scshape{\Large{\bfseries{Analysis of an innovative distribution system through a novel optimal power flow algorithm}}} 
        \end{center}

        \vfill
        \begin{normalsize}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \hspace{57pt} \textit{Laureando} \hspace{167pt} \textit{Relatore}\\
                \vspace{5pt}
                \hspace{30pt} \large{\textbf{Tommaso Faedo}} \hspace{70pt} \large{\textbf{Prof. Roberto Turri}}\\
                \vspace{10pt}
                \hspace{275pt} \normalsize{\textit{Correlatore}}\\
                \vspace{5pt}
                \hspace{241pt} \large{\textbf{Prof. Paolo Tenti}}\\
                \vspace{5pt}
                \hspace{172pt} \large{\textbf{Ing. Tommaso Caldognetto}}\\
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{normalsize}

        \vfill
        \begin{center}
            \hspace{-0.15cm}
            \line(1, 0){360}

            \hspace{0.01cm}\textsc{Anno Accademico 2017/2018}
        \end{center}
\vfill
    \end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect....that was exactly what I wanted...thanks man. Before I used \hspace{length} to center the elements of the cover of the thesis but it wasn't perfect. With your method is centered verticallyperfectly and automatically (for example if I change some word it change position automatically to go to the center vertically)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your questions, but a simpler solution:

```
% arara: frontespizio

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
\begin{Preambolo*}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\frontinstitutionfont}{\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries\scshape}
\renewcommand{\fronttitlefont}{\fontsize{17}{21}\bfseries\scshape}
\renewcommand{\frontfootfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\scshape}
\end{Preambolo*}
\Margini{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{2cm}
%
\Logo[2.5cm]{../duck}
\Filigrana[height=11.5cm]{../duck}
\Universita{Padova}
\Dipartimento{Ingegneria Industriale DII}
\Corso{Ingegneria dell'Energia Elettrica}
\Titolo{Analysis of an innovative distribution system
        through a novel optimal power flow algorithm}
\NCandidato{Laureando}
\Candidato{Tommaso Faedo}
\Relatore{Prof.\ Roberto Turri}
\Correlatore{Prof.\ Paolo Tenti}
\Correlatore{Ing.\ Tommaso Caldognetto}
\Annoaccademico{2017/2018}
\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I copy the code but Latex creates only a white paper.

Comment: @TommasoFaedo Did you read the manual? You have to run LaTeX on the `<filename>-frn.tex` file that's generated.

Comment: no, sorry. What I have to do?

Comment: done..I solve the problem...now I see the info